# Flyway in ECS: Create a task definition for db migration using flyway -example

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, flyway

I'm trying to create a task definition for db migration using flyway but without success. 
I cant find any example on google. 
To be specific, how will the `json` file should look like in the `CMD` part?

edit 
following @ydaetskcoR request - to make things clear
The code should be provisioned by terraform. After researching some code, I came up with this :

```
data "template_file" "db_mg_template" {
  template = 
  "${file("${path.module}/templates/task_definition_dbmgr.json")}"
  vars {
    container_memory = "${local.db_migrations_container_memory}"
    service_name     = "${local.db_migrations_svc_name}"
    cpu_limit        = "${local.db_migrations_cpu_limit}"
    vault_token      = "${var.vault_token}"
    consul_address   = "${var.consul_address}"
    command          = "${jsonencode(local.command)}"
  }
}
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "flyway" {
  container_definitions    = "${data.template_file.db_mg_template.rendered}"
  family                   = "${local.db_migrations_svc_name}"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = "${local.db_migrations_cpu_limit}"
  memory                   = "${local.db_migrations_container_memory}"
  execution_role_arn       = "${data.aws_iam_role.service_role.arn}"
  task_role_arn            = "${data.aws_iam_role.service_role.arn}"
}
```

And in my locals (pasting relevant code):

```
locals{
  command  = ["-url=jdbc:${local.db_type}://${data.consul_keys.this_db.var.db_address}",
              "-user=${data.consul_keys.this_db.var.db_username}",
              "-password=${data.vault_generic_secret.db_pass.data["value"]}",
              "-table=schema_version",
              "-location=filesystem:/tmp/DBChanges",
              "-sqlMigrationPrefix=v migrate"]
}
```

The goal is to run a container for flyway without restringing it to any service (like running docker container)
Hope this clear things 
Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information in your question as it stands to help you really. Could you show what commands you're currently running and any other input and how you are structuring your ECS service? Also if you have some Terraform code then add that to your question. If it errors then include the full error with enough surrounding context that a stranger can understand it. If it doesn't do what you want then explain what it's doing wrong as well.